# Script for rendering a specific frame n-times

Tags: animation, scripting, add-on

is there a script or an addon that let me render a specific frame n-times and change "only" the position of the camera (f.e. path animation) after the frame is rendered.

Comment: That's not really how it works. Rendering is through the camera and takes its position into account. You can't change the camera's location after you render. Or actually, you can - but you'll still get the same angle in all frames (because they've all been rendered before the camera moved).

So you can either change the camera's position via keyframe animation on the camera and then render the animation, or change the camera's location each frame and then render each frame using a script.

Comment: @TLousky - I think user2488 wants to change the position of the camera in between renders of the same frame. That's a sensible question.

Comment: @DaanMichiels, if that's the case then yes. That's just not how the question is phrased, so I added the comment above to make sure.

Comment: Yes that is right. 
I like to render a freezed action with some particles. The main problem is, that i need the motionblur for the particle. So converting the particlesystem an render my animation the "normal" way is not an option

Comment: How would you like to determine the position of the camera? Have it follow a curve?

Comment: a simple follow path would do it.

Comment: that sounds great! 

But i am not sure but i think i have heard about a addon that do that. But maybe that is only imagination :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me.
Add a *follow path* constraint to your camera. It is the *offset* of this constraint that we will change in order to move the camera.

- `camera_name`: name of the camera you want to move
- `constraint_name`: name of the constraint whose offset you want to animate
- `scene_name`: name of your scene
- `output_location`: where the rendered frames will be saved; if this is `/some/path/tiger` then your frames will be stored as `/some/path/tiger0`, `/some/path/tiger1`, ... (with file extensions added if this is in your scene settings)
- `initial_offset`, `final_offset`: initial and final offset that will be used for the constraint
- `nr_frames`: the total number of frames to render

Here's the code. It's very simple. To run it, just copy-paste into a new file in Blender's text editor, adjust settings and click Run Script.

```
#### Adjust these settings ####
camera_name = "Camera"
constraint_name = "Follow Path"
scene_name = "Scene"
output_location = "c:\\zoo\\elephant"

initial_offset = -10
final_offset = 10
nr_frames = 16
###############################

import bpy

# save now, so that we can restore these later
original_offset = bpy.data.objects[camera_name].constraints[constraint_name].offset
original_filepath = bpy.data.scenes[scene_name].render.filepath

# render the frames
for i in range(0, nr_frames):
    offset = initial_offset + (final_offset - initial_offset) * i / (nr_frames - 1)
    bpy.data.objects[camera_name].constraints[constraint_name].offset = offset
    bpy.data.scenes[scene_name].render.filepath = output_location + str(i)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)

#restore original values
bpy.data.scenes[scene_name].render.filepath = original_filepath
bpy.data.objects[camera_name].constraints[constraint_name].offset = original_offset
```